# Getting circular reference error for bean name 'prometheusMeterRegistry' using springboot actuator with Prometheus and RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I am getting 'prometheusMeterRegistry' bean is currently in creation error (see exact stacktrace below) when using Prometheus with springboot actuator along with RestTemplate. This seems to be due to circular reference of prometheusMeterRegistry when using along with RestTemplate/Builder that are autowired in my application and springboot dependency libraries.
I have spent all three days to analyze and fix the issue and referred solutions provided in several forums with No luck. I am getting this error at the time of server startup but surprisingly the /actuator/promethus url is coming up fine in my local but ofcourse without the rest api details as restTemplate has some dependency injection issue due to PrometheusMeterRegistry. When I deploy the same code on server (I attempted to deploy on server since it was working in local besides there are startup errors), due to error at startup the application is not getting deployed successfully on built-in tomcat server.
Please share your thoughts on how this can be addressed.

**Error stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsRestTemplateCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/client/RestTemplateMetricsConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'metricsRestTemplateCustomizer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'prometheusMeterRegistry': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1616)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.resolveStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.orderedStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2113)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.client.RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.restTemplateBuilderConfigurer(RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 140 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'prometheusMeterRegistry': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
```

As recommended in some of the forums I have also configured the below property to break the circular reference and it worked fine to break the cirular ref as it is intended but I got different error again at startup time. Below is the error.

property entry:

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

**Error stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthRegistryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/sample/monitor/MeterConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthRegistryCustomizer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1616)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1573)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1349)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.resolveStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2119)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.orderedStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2113)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.asOrderedList(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:90)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.customize(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:77)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.configure(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:63)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MeterRegistryPostProcessor.java:64)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    ... 111 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
```

Below is my implementation of RestTemplate and MeterRegistryCustomizer Bean

```java
    @Configuration
    public class MeterConfig {
        @Bean
        public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> healthRegistryCustomizer(@Autowired HealthContributorRegistry healthRegistry) {
    
            return  registry -> healthRegistry.stream()
                    .forEach(namedContributor -> registry.gauge("health",
                            details(namedContributor),
                            healthRegistry, health -> {
                                Status status = ((HealthIndicator) health
                                        .getContributor(namedContributor.getName()))
                                        .getHealth(true)
                                        .getStatus();
                                return healthToCode(status);
                            }));
        }

      private static  Iterable<Tag> details(NamedContributor<HealthContributor> contributor) {
        HealthContributor contrib = contributor.getContributor();
        HealthIndicator healthContributor = (HealthIndicator) contrib;
        String name = contributor.getName();
        List<Tag> tagList = new ArrayList<>();
        tagList.add(Tag.of("name", name));
        String details = healthContributor.getHealth(true).getDetails().toString();
        tagList.add(Tag.of("details", details));
        return tagList;
    }

    public static int healthToCode(Status status) {
        return status.equals(Status.UP) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableScheduling
    public class AppConfig {
        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
            return restTemplateBuilder.build();
        }
    }

    @Component
    public class MyHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
        
        @Autowired
        MyRepo myrepo;
        
        @Override
        public Health health() {
            return myrepo.ping() == "SUCCESS" ? Health.UP.build(): Health.DOWN.build(); //this will return the 
        }
    }

    @Repository
    public class MyRepo {
        
        @Autowired
        RestTemplate restTemplate;
        
        public String ping() {
                return restTemplate.exchange("url", GET, new HttpEntity(requestBody, headers), String.class);
        }
    }
```

If you observe in my code, I have tried @Lazy initialization and @DependsOn as well to delay the bean initilization assuming that PrometheusMeterRegistry MeterRegistry bean creation is dependent on restTemplate/PrometheusMeterRegistry.

I might be doing something wrong here with respect to injecting beans. Please share your thoughts of how to fix this.
I am using Springboot 2.7.2 and dependency management to control dependency versions and also added dependency for io.micrometer registry for prometheus.

Comment: The relationship between your `MeterRegistryCustomizer` and your `RestTemplate` bean isn't clear to me. Can you explain that a bit more? All `MeterRegistryCustomizer` beans are called during the creation of the `MeterRegistry` so a customizer shouldn't `@DependOn` the registry as that will create a cycle. You may want to try implementing `MeterBinder` rather than `MeterRegistryCustomizer`. I am not sure that it will solve your problem, but it is a better callback to use for binding gauges (and any other type of meter) to a registry.

Comment: If you look at the MeterRegistryCustomizer bean in my code, it has implementation to call custom healthIndicator which in turn calls rest apis ping. The ping call uses resttemplate. They are not directly related. I got multiple custom Health Indicator implementations in my app to check the health of all downstream apis. The intention behind MeterRegistryCustomizer is to register each HealthIndicator and gauge the health to capture the status separately in the response.

Comment: Here is the reference code for above comment.

Comment: Below is the supporting code for the above comment.


`@Component
public class MyHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
 
 @Autowired
 MyRepo myrepo;
 
 @Override
 public Health health() {
  return myrepo.ping() == "SUCCESS" ? Health.UP.build(): Health.DOWN.build(); //this will return the 
 }
}

@Repository
public class MyRepo {
 
 @Autowired
 RestTemplate restTemplate;
 
 public String ping() {
   return restTemplate.exchange("url", GET, new HttpEntity(requestBody, headers), String.class);
 }
}`

Comment: Please edit your question to add that code and everything else needed to provide a complete picture. You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as well.

Comment: Updated the question with code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sharing my experience as it took more time checking the root cause of that circular reference.
I faced the same issue with prometheusMeterRegistry after upgrading to sprintboot 2.6.x and 2.7.x As I had dependency on micrometer-registry-prometheus in my POM file.

The code was setting the metricRegistry of prometheus manually to HikariDataSource, however in the new version springboot, it happens automatically with each Hikari datasource, so simply I removed that code from my method then it worked fine.

```
@Bean(name = "myDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource(/* final MeterRegistry metricRegistry */) {
    final var dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
   /* if (dataSource instanceof HikariDataSource) {
        final var hikariDs = (HikariDataSource) dataSource;
        hikariDs.setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
    } */

    return dataSource;
}
```

Note: Setting the `spring.main.allow-circular-references=true` didn't work with my multiple datasources project.

Hope it could help.

Comment: you sir deserve a thumb up